# "The"+ "plural noun" for a general statement

Tags: grammar

I read this rule about making a general statement from Practical English Usage of Swan, that says:

When we generalize about members of a group, we usually use no article. But if we talk about the group as a whole- as if was a well-known unit, we are more likely to use the.
Example:

> (1)Nurses mostly work very hard (nearly every individual)
>
> (2)The nurses have never gone on strike ( the well- known professional
> body)

I know that we use "the nurses" ( the +plural noun) when we refer to a specific situation, for example:
The nurses **in my hospital** have never gone on strike.

But I don't know the difference between (1) and (2) for making a general statement.

Comment: I don't think there's much (if any) truth in your assertion *(for a well-known unit, we are more likely to use **the**)*. It's true that the article is more *likely* to be included in a highly specific context such as *[The] nurses in my hospital have never gone on strike*, but even that is only a *tendency* (that sentence is still fine without initial ***the***). There's no real difference between your examples #1 and #2, where *either* version would only normally include the article in some context where "nurses" are being "particularised" (as distinct from ***other*** professions).

Comment: I want to make a general statement: (1) The nurses work harder than the teachers or (2) Nurses works harder than teachers. Both are correct. Right?

Comment: where either version would only normally include the article in some context where "nurses" are being "particularised" (as distinct from other professions).==> I actually don’t get what you mean here. Could you please help me give me an example to illustrate this?

Comment: *We all work hard at Northwick Park Teaching Hospital, but I'd say the nurses work harder than the teachers* (highly specific; articles effectively *required*). *Most people would say that nurses work harder than teachers* (general assertion; articles effectively *optional*).

Comment: Most people would say that nurses work harder than teachers (general assertion; articles effectively optional).==>For this general assertion, what is the difference between the sentence with and without "the"?

Comment: Like I said, for the general assertion those articles are effectively *optional* (but wouldn't normally be included, because the reference is to ***all*** nurses / teachers). For the Northwick Park *specific* case, the articles *would* normally be included (because the reference is to ***those contextually-specific*** nurses and teachers). But whether you include articles or not doesn't change the meanings of either of my examples - it's just a matter of whether native speakers would be *likely* to include them in those assertions.

Comment: It seems that when talking about something in general  and specific situations, "the" doesn't have a specific meaning. I can make a sentence as a general statement or a statement about a specific situation with or with out "the",  and the inclusion of "the" or not is just a style preference of each person. Right?

Comment: (3). People who love reading books often love dogs.
(4). The people who love reading books often love dogs. 
Both are correct for a general statment. Right?

Comment: Both your examples #3 and #4 are syntactically fine, but #4 wouldn't occur very often. I think you're confusing "a general statement" = "a general truth" = "an assertion which is universally acknowledged" with the fact that ***The** people who love reading* = ***Those particular** people who love reading* (a ***specific*** subset of "people in general = everyone"). Strictly speaking, both #3 and #4 are statements about the same *particular* group of people - it's just that #4 emphasises that particularity more explicitly (but if that was important, we'd say ***those***, not ***the***).

Comment: After reading a lot of posts on this forum. I have come to an conclusion that the definite "the" in this structure "the+plural noun" seems to be optional for both general statements and statements about a specific situation.
But people is likely to omit "the" in general statements and include "the" in statements of specific situation.

Right?